# MySQL DB error in displaying table

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu

I have a problem when I backup my database from old server to the new one. Both run Ubuntu. The difference is the old database is using phpmyadmin 1.6.3 and the new one is 5.7.21. I lost some tables but it appear in the sidebar. Can anyone describe to me what is going on with my db? Here is the screenshot. [image]

to be clear, here is the screenshot of my old database phpmyadmin interface. 
[image]

Comment: " the old database is using phpmyadmin 1.6.3 ...". Databases ***do not*** use phpMyAdmin; you use phpMyAdmin to view and manipulate databases. I am guessing that your phpMyAdmin configuration changed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try stop and start the `mysqld` service.

If the error still exists then back up the `database file` and `drop` it then import again to a newly created database.

**commands may be OS specific

follow instructions from : [MySQL Site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-find-table.html)